# does eclipse come with inbuilt package javax.sound.sampled.*?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm currently using Eclipse Kepler for JAVA application development.
I want to create an application that can play sound.
Most of solution available on stackoverflow are using javax.sound.sampled* package. But i did not find it in my eclipse.
Is this package INBUILT ? or is there any way to install this package? Do newer versions of eclipse have this package?

Comment: That is part of the standard Java runtime.

Comment: I tried to use   import javax.sound.sampled.*;                                                                            My eclipse does not seem to have that package. How can i import that package? @greg-449

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update your Eclipse.
Steps:
-Go to Help Option in the Menu Bar
-Click on "Check for updates"
-After it is successfully updated, you will get sound package.
It worked for me.